# How to properly parse this xml response

Tags: c#, sql, xml

We are using a currency service for currency exchange.  There xml web response is not in the greatest format.  It looks like such

```
<RESPONSE>
   <EXPR>USD</EXPR> 
   <EXCH>CAD</EXCH> 
   <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT> 
   <NPRICES>1</NPRICES> 
   <CONVERSION>
      <DATE>Thu, 07 Apr 2011 21:00:00 GMT</DATE> 
      <ASK>1.0418</ASK> 
      <BID>1.0415</BID> 
   </CONVERSION>
   <EXPR>USD</EXPR> 
   <EXCH>AUD</EXCH> 
   <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT> 
   <NPRICES>1</NPRICES> 
   <CONVERSION>
      <DATE>Thu, 07 Apr 2011 21:00:00 GMT</DATE> 
      <ASK>1.0461</ASK> 
      <BID>1.0459</BID> 
   </CONVERSION>
</RESPONSE>
```

So I tried to write the following SQL Statement

```
SELECT 
    T.c.value('../EXPR[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)')
,   T.c.value('../EXCH[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)')
,   T.c.value('ASK[1]', 'MONEY')
FROM @xml.nodes('/RESPONSE/CONVERSION') T(c)
```

But since both Headers (EXPR and EXCH) are on the same level, is there anyway I can pick the Expr that is above the conversion.  **And without reading as a text file in C#.**  
I understand how I would accomplish that.

Comment: Wow! Whoever came up with that response format should be sent back to school.

Comment: Are you trying to do this all in SQL too?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in SQL or C#? If you aren't looking for a C# answer you may want to remove that tag.

Comment: @Bala R - Agreed - those date representations are atrocious.  They are culture specific - never a good idea.

Comment: I can do it in either C# or Sql since I am making the web call in a c# program anyway.  Again I have a text reader solution but don't know if it is the best.  I was also thinking of using @xml.modify to try and insert the needed level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to select all the EXPR, EXCH, and ASK nodes in document-order, and join them on the assigned row-number:

```
select
    exprn.val
,   exchn.val
,   askn.val
FROM 
(select expr.e.value('.', 'VARCHAR(3)') as val, row_number() over(order by expr.e) n from @xml.nodes('/RESPONSE/EXPR') expr(e)) exprn

join (select exch.e.value('.', 'VARCHAR(3)') as val, row_number() over(order by exch.e) n from @xml.nodes('/RESPONSE/EXCH') exch(e)) exchn on exchn.n = exprn.n

join (select ask.a.value('.', 'MONEY') as val, row_number() over(order by ask.a) n from @xml.nodes('/RESPONSE/CONVERSION/ASK') ask(a)) askn on askn.n = exprn.n
```

Answer (score 1):

If your nodes are always in the same order, you can try the following before beginning to parse is:

1) Remove the ,  tags: e.g. xmlString = xmlString.Replace("", string.empty) ...

2) Split your string: entries[] = xmlString.Split(""); or use Regex.Split

3) Add missing tags to all entries: , ,

4) Parse the entries

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like this:

```
using System.Xml;

public class TestClass
{
    void ParseXML(string xml)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        XmlNodeList list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("EXPR");
    }
}
```

In that example `list[0]` should contain the first instance of the EXPR tag.

Comment: This is how we do it at work. And then we use BULK sql command to copy it to db.